# Tab completion for my vim command don't work

Tags: vim

I have created this vim command:

```
command! -complete=file E vsplit | wincmd l | e
```

When I use it by this

```
:E <Tab>
```

It works as expected. But when i want to complete path relatively to home directory, it shows ^I for each TAB hit:

```
:E ~/<TAB>
# shows as:
:E ~/^I
```

For :e command tab-completion works good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify how many arguments:

```
command! -complete=file -nargs=? E vsplit | wincmd l | e <args>
```

See `:h :command-nargs`

However you are re-creating a command that already exists `:vsplit` and using `'splitright'` setting. Put `set splitright` in your `vimrc` and now you can use `:vsplit` directly.

```
:set splitright
:vsp foo.txt
```

If you do not feel like setting `'splitright'` then you can use `:rightbelow`. Example:

```
:rightb vsp foo.txt
```

For more help see:

```
:h 'splitright'
:h :vsp
:h :command-nargs
:h :rightbelow
```